# Why won't Django recognize the application I created?

Tags: python, django, startapp

I created a directory called `project1` with the path `C:\DP`. When I run the server for project1 using

`python C:\DP\project1\manage.py runserver`

it works perfectly. Then I create a new app using

`python C:\DP\project1\manage.py startapp rango`

I then move the `rango` directory to the `C:\DP` path. Inside of project1's `settings.py` file I add `rango` the the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple so it looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rango',
```

)

When I run the project1 server again, I get an error saying:

```
ImportError: No module named 'rango'
```

How can I get Django to recognize that `rango` has been added?

Comment: You moved the app module out of the project. Of course this won't work.

Comment: Why did you move it? `app`'s live inside `projects`. If you want a separate apop start a new project and add an app to that.

Comment: When creating the app module it was created outside of the project and i wasn't sure where to move it.

Comment: What folder did you move `rango` out from? Where was it created?

Comment: It was moved from `C:\Users\PC`